# Calculating Probability Using Bayes?

Tags: probability, bayesian

> A recent survey of residents in Texas concluded that 55% of Austin city residents and 46% of Houston city residents broke a bone at some point during their childhood.

> Let’s say Austin has 5200 residents, and Houston has 4500. You independently choose two residents with replacement from the combined 9700 and learn that both of them broke a bone as a child. What’s the probability that the two residents live in different cities?

For this problem, I'm assuming I have to use Bayes, where I multiply the probability that both broke a bone given they live in different cities by the probability that both live in different cities divided by the probability that both broke a bone. However, I have no clue how to get the probabilities or what their values are, or if I'm even using the right formula.

Comment: The problem description (which is entirely counterfactual, by the way) enables you to conceive of filling a box with 9700 tickets.  On every ticket is the name of a city and an indication of a bone break--and you are given enough information to know how many of all four possible tickets there are.  Thus, you can compute any probability you want about what shows up when two tickets are randomly withdrawn from that box.